# Is there a command that allows you to restart a pm2 app if a file in another directory is changed?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have an Ubuntu server that is running plesk obsidian to manage my websites, on the same server I have a nodejs application running with pm2.

There is a json file that a website and the application needs to access. I am able to make the app's code point to the file and access it, but when the website makes changes to the file it doesn't automatically restart the nodejs app as the file isn't in the same directory.

Is there a command that I can use to make pm2 check for changes with the json file and restart the app?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a command

```
pm2 start app.js --watch
```

here app.js is the file name which cause pm2 to restart

Comment: I am aware of this command but the file i want to watch is in a different directory to the app. If I recall correctly, --watch only looks for changes in the root folder, where the app is located and any of its subfolders. However, I have a solution to what i wanted to achieve. Thank you for commenting and trying to help :)